# Let canvas.toDataUrl get the right dimension of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

My dream is save the content of a div to pdf. Currently i'm using Html2pdf in this way:

```
function pdfFatt() {
        var idFatt = 1;
        var dataFatt = 1;

        var div = document.querySelector('.default_template_holder');

        if(div_stampa){
            html2canvas(div, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 297);
                    doc.save('fatt_'+idFatt+'_'+dataFatt+'.pdf');
                }
            });
        }else{

        }
}
```

The problem is resolution, infact all works but the resolution of image is really bad. (Screenshot 1).

Surfing the net i have finded the solution, i will zoom the canvas! so my code is this

```
function pdfFatt() {
        var idFatt = 1;
        var dataFatt = 1;

        var scaleBy = 2;
        var w = 2480;
        var h = 3508;
        var div = document.querySelector('.default_template_holder');
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = w * scaleBy;
        canvas.height = h * scaleBy;
        canvas.style.width = w + 'px';
        canvas.style.height = h + 'px';
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.scale(scaleBy, scaleBy);

        if(div_stampa){
            html2canvas(div, {
                canvas:canvas,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 297);
                    doc.save('fatt_'+idFatt+'_'+dataFatt+'.pdf');
                }
            });
        }else{

        }
}
```

The resolution now is ok, but the image not fit the canvas!! I need to add the parameter "canvas:canvas" on html2pdf function or it won't get the zooming. (Screenshot 2).

Is there a way for obtaining the (screenshot 1) with the resolution of (Screenshot 2)?

Thanks a lot.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsRwo.jpg)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4zh5.jpg)

My code that resolves the issue is:

```
    function pdfFatt() {
   //selezione elementi nella visuale della fattura
   var menu = document.querySelector('.vertical_menu_area'); 
   var div = document.querySelector('.default_template_holder');
   var barra = document.querySelector('.fattura-strumenti');

   //controllo esistenza dei 3 elementi fondamentali
   if(div && menu && barra){

      //id e data fattura per nome pdf
      var idFatt = $j(".fattura-sub-intestazione input[name='id-fattura']").val();
      var dataFatt = $j(".fattura-sub-intestazione input[name='data-fattura']").val();

          //creazione canvas scalato x 2 per alta risoluzione
          var scaleBy = 2;
      var w_menu = menu.offsetWidth;
      var h_menu = menu.offsetHeight;
          var w_div = div.offsetWidth;
      var h_div = div.offsetHeight;
          var div_style = div.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(div);
          var mar_div_w = parseFloat(div_style.marginLeft);
          var mar_div_h = parseFloat(div_style.marginTop);
          var w_barra = barra.offsetWidth;
      var h_barra = barra.offsetHeight;
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.width = w_div * scaleBy;
      canvas.height = h_div * scaleBy;
          context.scale(scaleBy, scaleBy);
          context.translate(-w_menu-w_barra-mar_div_w-8,-mar_div_h);
      context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
          context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
          context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
          context.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";

          //creazione pdf con script html2canvas
      html2canvas(div, {
         canvas:canvas,
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 297);
        doc.save('fattura_'+idFatt+'_'+dataFatt+'.pdf');
          }
       });
   }else{
      alert("Impossibile salvare la fattura");
   }
}
```

Comment: If i append the canvas to body i see the image in a good resolution and right dimension, i think the problem is when i get the dataUrl of canvas

Comment: it's not the data URL which is the issue, it's only a value, but it's how your canvas behaves when converted into a PDF file, try to manipulate the canvas initialization(width,height and etc) and see the difference after. We can't help you with the above code you provided.

Comment: Set the div size to 2480  3508, scale the content of the div to fit, then let HTML2Canvas create the canvas, and you just set the size `html2Canvas(div, onrendered : toPDF, width : 2480, height : 3508); function toPDF(canvas){ var doc = new jsPDF(); doc.addImage(canvas, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 297); doc.save("file.pdf");};`

Comment: I've done!! I've mixed yours idea (expecially thanks to @Roljhon)

Comment: @Andrea good to know! please put your answer below to help others in the future as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is correct you just have to get the width and height of your `var div` and use that for  `jsPDF()` and `.addImage` dimensions, regarding on the resolution try adding `dpi:300` option and fix your browser scale to 1. I updated your code below:

```
function pdfFatt() {
        var idFatt = 1;
        var dataFatt = 1;

        var scale = 'scale(1)'; // For Fix Zoom of browser
        document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scale;    // Chrome, Opera, Safari
        document.body.style.msTransform =   scale;       // IE 9
        document.body.style.transform = scale;     // General    

        var div = document.querySelector('.default_template_holder');
        var width = div.offsetWidth;
        var height = div.offsetHeight;

        if(div_stampa){
            html2canvas(div, {
                dpi:300,
                scale:2,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "px", [width,height]);
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
                    doc.save('fatt_'+idFatt+'_'+dataFatt+'.pdf');
                }
            });
        }else{

        }
}
```

Comment: Tanks Mark! Will try tomorrow and let you know :)

Comment: Hi Mark, your code is much more clear and works very good but the problem is the image resolution! The image looks blur and,with my code,I’ve resolved this scaling canvas x 2. Do you have any suggest to resolve with your code? Many thanks

Comment: I just edited my code, Just adjust var scale = 'scale(2)'; // For Higher Resolution. Tell me if that works

Comment: Mark it not works, all the document scale x 2 and the pdf generated is not good. I provide you with some screenshot. Scale 1 web (https://imgur.com/a/miCFwvb), Scale 1 PDF (https://imgur.com/a/qBBJSDP), Scale 2 web (https://imgur.com/a/7XkyTOe), Scale 2 pdf (https://imgur.com/a/ZtgorQn). Thanks

Comment: Oh.Sorry for that, I just edit my code above, turn back "var scale = 'scale(1)';" for fix zoom of browser and added "scale:2" on html2canvas option. Tell me if that works :)

Comment: Hi Mark! it not works :( the quality is ever bad, it looks like that the image has not been scaled. I've already tried to scale more or insert my solution, but with my solution I need ever to translate the context manually based on each computer (in the office computer it works but in mine not, i need to set other parameters to translate good). I love your solution because it is scalable, universal and clear but the quality is important too. Many Thanks

Comment: Understood. Sorry if I can only see your whole code. I assume you're required to use hardcoded dimensions. Hopefully code above still gives you small help somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! Many thanks!  now, thanks to you, the code is adjusted to translate automatically based on what the div is getting in the view, there are some other components to consider. Have a good day